# Unable to sort in Altair bar-chart

Tags: python, bar-chart, altair

Can't get Altair to sort a column. It seems to have a mind of it's own. Trying to sort by 'count'.

```
countries_df = pd.DataFrame(countries_top10, columns=["Country", "count"])
countries_df.sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

alt.Chart(countries_df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('count', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field='count', order='descending')),
    y="Country"
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=16,
    titleFontSize=16).properties(
    width='container').interactive()
```

Output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO70I.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to get it working

```
alt.Chart(countries_df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count',
    y=alt.Y('Country:N', sort='-x')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `EncodingSortField` approach only applies to ordinal or nominal scales; your scale is quantitative, so the sort order is going to follow the quantitative axis.

It looks like your goal is to reverse the domain, which you can do like this:

```
    x=alt.X('count', sort='descending'),
```